# Visual Studio Community 2019 slow loading (start without debugging) on c# (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, performance

I recently got a new hp pavilion gaming laptop and downloaded Visual studio 2019 on it, I study IT and I do my projects for now with the "C#: Console App (.Net Framework)" . But unlike with my old laptop, when I start the project (even with extremely simple commands like console.writeline) without debugging (Which supposedly should load instantly), it's taking about 15 seconds or more to load which is becoming really frustrating for me. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this performance issue and below had helped me.

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > c# > Advanced > Select 'Open Documents' under 'Background Aalysis scope'.

Also go to task manager and end `ServiceHub.RoselynCodeAnalysisService.exe`